# Connect to SAP HANA with Python using SSO

Tags: python, single-sign-on, hana

I have tried connecting to SAP Hana with Python using SSO but without success. Can somebody please help?

Regards
Ravi Krishnan

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
# Import Library
import pyodbc

# Define ODBC-Driver   
db_conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='P30')

# Define SQL-Query
sql_query = """
    SELECT
        x,
        y
    FROM
        datasource
"""
# Execute SQL-Query
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, db_conn)
```

No user or password needed.